# How do I add a pixel of space between my inputs?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin, display

I have these fields in a search form …

```
<form id="search-form" action="/events/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="searchField">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="searchField">
    <input type="text" name="event" id="event" placeholder="Event" class="searchField">
    <input alt="Search" type="image" src="http://www.racertracks.com/assets/magnifying-glass-0220f37269f90a370c3bb60229240f2ef2a4e15b335cd42e64563ba65e4f22e4.png" class="search_button">
</form>
```

then I have this style for the form …

```
#search-form {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Problem is, the elements appear right next to each other — https://jsfiddle.net/fmy1syfw/ .  I would like at least a pixel of space between them to not make everything seem so cramped.  I have tried adding

```
margin: 1px;
```

to the above style, but to no avail.  How do I add a pixel of space between my elements without breaking the behavior of the form at different screen widths?

Comment: Give the margin to the `#search-form input { }` ... https://jsfiddle.net/fmy1syfw/1/

Comment: Unfortunately that breaks everything.  Compress the screen to less than 680 pixels with your Fiddle and compare that to compressing mine with less than 680 pixels.  Things no longer line up the same.

Comment: That's because you are setting a fixed width, you can use flex-grow instead https://jsfiddle.net/fmy1syfw/3/

Comment: With a few fix on flex values, max-width and margins, would this be the expected result : https://jsfiddle.net/fmy1syfw/5/ or https://jsfiddle.net/fmy1syfw/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add margin as required to the inputs and remove it in your media queries (again, as required).

Since you have used fixed widths of 50% in you media query, these will have to be adjusted using `calc` to account for the extra margin.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
#logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
#searchForm {
  padding: 20px;
}
#search-form {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
#last_name,
#event {
  margin-left: 1px;
}
#first_name,
#last_name {
  width: 20%;
}
#event {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
/* Do not specify width to allow it to grow freely */

.search_button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
/* Predefine image dimensions to ensure proper aspect ratio */

#loginArea {
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 580px;
}
@media (max-width: 620px) {
  #search-form {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  #first_name {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #last_name {
    width: calc(50% - 1px);
    margin-left: 1px;
  }
  #event {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    margin: 0;
  }
}
.searchField {
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div id="loginArea">

  <div id="searchForm">
    Search For Results
    <br />
    <div>
      <form id="search-form" action="/events/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="searchField">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="searchField">
        <input type="text" name="event" id="event" placeholder="Event" class="searchField">
        <input alt="Search" type="image" src="http://www.racertracks.com/assets/magnifying-glass-0220f37269f90a370c3bb60229240f2ef2a4e15b335cd42e64563ba65e4f22e4.png" class="search_button">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tbausb1g/)

Comment: Thanks but I want a pixel of space between the elements on a small screen as well.  I tried increasing "margin:0" in your media queries to "margin:1px" but that breaks everything on the small screen.

Comment: Then you can't use fixed widths of 50% - https://jsfiddle.net/tbausb1g/ You'll have to adjust using `calc`.